# connecting PBI to impala

Tags: powerbi, impala, cloudera-cdh

I created a cloudera cluster (ENTERPRISE DATA HUB) on azure. I can use the DNSname:7180  to view and manage cluster. However, I am not successfull in connecting to the Impala from PowerBI Desktop. I tried both VM names with dn0 and mn0 extension ([myhostname]-dn0.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com) and ports 71890, 21000, 21050, based on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pliu/2017/01/17/ssh-tunnel-to-endpoints-in-azure-vnet-from-windows/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-impala)
It always fail at the authentication level. I tried anonymous, windows and DB authentication, and they all failed with this error:

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ImpalaODBC] (100) Error from the Impala Thrift API: connect() failed: errno = 10060"
```

Any help or clue is appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar error while trying to connect to impala. Most probably your connection is failing due to access permissions, firewall or even proxy. Make sure that you are indicating the right IP for host and the corresponding port. You should also be aware of "thriftpy" version of the packages which in my case are installed in python through conda.

Answer (score 0):

The port is 21050. You have to open it on Azure VM since it is not open by default.